# Quantify the difference among arrays order

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

Let suppose that i have two or more arrays/lists containing the same elements, but with different order.

```
MyClass[] array1 = new MyClass[] {obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4};
MyClass[] array2 = new MyClass[] {obj1, obj4, obj2, obj3};
```

I need an algorithm for comparing and calculate the order difference of the elements in the arrays, something like:

```
double likeness = ArraysOrderComparator.compare(array1, array2);
```

I think there are different ways to do it.
Basically, i want to define a metric for comparing the order of differente arrays.
I bet some algorithms which do it already exist, can someone give me an hint?
I need to implement it in java code.

Comment: Define 'order difference'. For example, what would you expect `likeness` to equal?

Comment: There are definitely multiple ways of comparing orders, but the correct solution would probably require a better understanding of what the comparison will be used for. A basic idea may be to simplify such that your arrays are effectively just strings, you could use any string differencing algorithm (such as hamming distance). I assume in your case ('1234','1423') would be less alike than say ('1234','1243')

Comment: Actually i need to explore the different ways i can compute `likeness`, so i'd like to have keywords to google some theory about it!
For my purpose, i should give more importance to relative order difference rather than absolute order ('1234' should be more similar to '1423' than to '1432')

Comment: I think you need to think a bit more about your actual requirements.  We can discuss technical implementation once you've done that.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i wasn't clear. I don't need help about implementation, i need to know if there is one or more algorithms which measure the 'order difference' or if I have to create one from scratch.
('1234','1423') should be more alike than ('1234','1432') because the relative order among items '23' is preserved in the first case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List of algorithms you are searching for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric)

You can compare your arrays with any of these algorithms to get a defined "likelyness" of your choice. To apply these algorithms on more general data, define:

- Each distinct object of all your arrays as "letter"
- Each array as "string"

That's all you need to pick the one you need and implement it.

Comment: thanks! Since i'm handling less than 257 elements, i'm just going to cast items IDs (int going from 0 to 200) to char and build strings from the way they are ordered in the arrays.  Also, searching for already-done implementations, i found this: https://github.com/tdebatty/java-string-similarity

Comment: Thanks! The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance helped me a lot. For small-ish arrays (<2000) the exhaustive (n²) version is also easy to implement.